# Format / filter an output with regular expression in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, filter, format, angularjs-ng-repeat

Given this:

```
        <span ng-repeat="extra in extras">
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-click="addExtra()"  value="{{extra.id}}" >{{extra.name}} - <strong>{{extra.real_price}}</strong>
        </span>
```

How do i make the {{extra.real_price}} to output only numbers  using filters ?

Example: 
extra.real_price being 'from 400€' to transform to '400'

Answer (score 2):

you can use a regexp to strip out all characters except numeric ones:

```
app.filter('onlyNumbers', function () {
    return function (item) {
      return item.replace(/[^\d|^,|^.]/g, '');
    }
  });
```

The regexp can be read: replace all characters not being a number, nor a comma nor a point.

Note that, as you are using currency values, both point and comma should be accepted values.

These are some examples of usage and output:

```
{{ '23345€' | onlyNumbers }}       => 23345
{{ '$23345' | onlyNumbers }}       => 23345
{{ '$23345.00' | onlyNumbers }}    => 23345.00
{{ '23345,00 €' | onlyNumbers }}   => 23345,00
```

Comment: Was this answer all right? Please consider accepting it :)